# Writing records into Snowflake from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the Kafka Connect connector for Snowflake, where I am receiving small batches of records in my topic and then writing them into stage tables within Snowflake.  This works fine.

I would then like to process the records for each microbatch *immediately after* they are written to Snowflake in an event-driven way.  That is, by not running code on a time-based schedule.  Ideally, the Kafka connector would trigger the processing, passing the topic name and the starting and ending offsets for the microbatch.

Is there a best way to achieve this?  I don't think this is natively supported in the Kafka connector, but I was thinking I could listen to the **_consumer_offsets** topic and when the connector commits the offsets to the broker, that would signal my code to start processing.

/ Joe

Comment: Sounds like you might want something of a job scheduler system like Spark or NiFi rather than just a connector

Comment: Yes, I may need to switch from using the connector to writing my own stream processor, but wanted to use the connector if possible.

Comment: The other option is forking the connector (assuming it's open-source), then adding your own logic to it

Comment: I'd agree with @JoeP best way to do this is too write a custom streaming application, as kafka connector uses Snowpipe. That's not as hard as it seems. You could write each record using jdbc. Beware this will result in (probably significanly) higher costs to ingest data. Also snowflake isn't not streaming data platform, so if you want to do streaming analyses I'd not use snowflake.

Comment: We ended up writing our own customer streaming sink.  It's configurable to either use JDBC for small workloads and Snowpipe for larger ones.  There's a numeric config setting called SnowpipeThreshold that you can set.  If the number of records in the microbatch are under the threshold, it uses JDBC.  If over, it invokes Snowpipe and also detects when the records have been written to the target table in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Consuming and following records from `_consumer_offsets` may not scale well as the amount of noise (from unrelated consumers and topics) increases in your organization's use of Kafka.

There are probably multiple ways to achieve this but the closest one can get to the event that indicates a write to Snowflake [has been completed and is ready for commit](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-kafka-connector/blob/master/src/main/java/com/snowflake/kafka/connector/SnowflakeSinkTask.java#L206-L216) is by hooking directly into the Kafka Connect interface.

Per [Kafka Connect architecture](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html), and Snowflake's implementation of the Connect APIs, a light wrapper class that performs additional logic after every completed flush event can be used.

The [`preCommit` call](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/WorkerSinkTask.java#L367-L379) in every running task object [is called as part of a continuous loop](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/WorkerSinkTask.java#L191-L192), typically once every minute (or ""offset.flush.interval.ms" long). A `postCommit` would be the most ideal but that does not exist in the APIs yet.

A very basic example that hooks your logic into the `preCommit` API call would look like this:

```java
class WrappedSnowflakeSinkTask extends com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkTask {

  @Override
  public Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> preCommit(
    Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets)
    throws RetriableException {

    Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets = super.preCommit();

    // Invoke Snowflake processing logic here using the offsets object,
    // preferably in an asynchronous manner (submit a callable to a threadpool, etc.) and
    // with an initial submit/sleep delay of over 1-2 minutes or "offset.flush.timeout.ms",
    // whichever is higher, to account for potential commit timeouts after this returns.
    doOwnLogic(offsets, …);

    return offsets;
  }

}
```

Also write a connector class, a very basic wrapper that only overrides the SinkTask class method to enforce the class created above:

```java
class WrappedSnowflakeConnector extends com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector {
  @Override
  public Class<? extends Task> taskClass() {
    return WrappedSnowflakeSinkTask.class;
  }
}
```

Build and deploy the wrapped connector (WrappedSnowflakeConnector) in place of the original Snowflake Connector.